# Link it's node link to the node:body in views

Tags: views, navigation, nodes

I can only link it to it's node when its a node:title field when making a certain view. how can I link it to the node:body? Is there are reference id?

Comment: You can't link the body as it usually contains block-level HTML tags (`<p>`, `<div>`, etc) which can't be wrapped in an `<a>` tag

Comment: I shudder to think what worm hole would be opened if the body contained `<a>` tags as well :)

Answer (score 1):

In all seriousness, you could do this by first including the node:nid in your view and then rewriting node:body as a link to node/[nid] in the configuration.  What might happen with all the content of that body inside of that though is undetermined.  I would hope views would check_plain it or remove tags etc so that just text is linked but I've never done it to see.

Comment: It works ! Yes! :D

Answer (score 0):

There is a module to achieve: https://drupal.org/project/linked_field

Then you can add any link to any field in manage display page admin/structure/types/manage/[node_type]/display